# PyTest-Mock not working due to AttributeError

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to use PyTest_Mock in order to do some testing in my Python project. I created a very simple test to try it out, but I am getting an AttributeError and I don't know why.

**model.py**

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = square(5)
    print("result: {}".format(res))
```

**test_model.py**

```
import pytest
from pytest_mock import mocker

import model

def test_model():
    mocker.patch(square(5))

    assert model.square(5) == 25
```

After running `python -m pytest` I get a failure and the following error:

```
    def test_model():
>       mocker.patch(square(5))
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'patch'

test_model.py:7: AttributeError
```

Comment: Can you show us directory structure? tree.

Comment: Both files are in the root directory along with an empty `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't need to import `mocker`, it's available as fixture, so you just pass it as a parameter in the test function:

   ```
   def test_model(mocker):
       mocker.patch(...)
   ```
2. `square(5)` evaluates to 25, so `mocker.patch(square(5))` will effectively try to patch a number 25. Instead, pass the function name as parameter: either

   ```
   mocker.patch('model.square')
   ```

   or

   ```
   mocker.patch.object(model, 'square')
   ```
3. Once patched, `square(5)` will not return 25 anymore since the original function is replaced with a mock object that can return anything and will return a new mock object by default. `assert model.square(5) == 25` will thus fail. Usually, you patch stuff either to avoid complex test setup or simulate behaviour of components that is desired in test scenario (for example, a website being unavailable). In your example, you don't need mocking at all.

Complete working example:

```
import model

def test_model(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(model, 'square', return_value='foo')

assert model.square(5) == 'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made this example just so I could understand the basics of mocking in Python and your explanation helped perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I'm not able to run the test without importing mocker. Where does it enter the namespace if not imported in the test file?

Comment: @geekly `mocker` is a fixture provided by the [`pytest-mock`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) plugin. `pytest` collects all fixtures on a test run start and automatically injects their return values in place of test function arguments that match the fixture names. Best is to check out the docs: [pytest fixtures: explicit, modular, scalable](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still wondering how it finds the mocker fixture if I don't even import it. I understand that pytest-mock is a separate module, not part of pytest. It sounds like the minimum requirement for using it is to install the pytest-module and reference 'mocker' in the test code. Is that true?

Comment: Exactly. The verbose explanation of the `pytest` magic won't fit into a comment, but what basically happens when you run the tests is: `pytest` imports all modules from the project root dir, looks at all imported functions, filters out those that are marked with `@pytest.fixture` and builds a fixture cache (a dict mapping fixture name to python function). The test functions are also preprocessed into special objects wrapping the functions and test function arguments are analyzed: if an argument has the same name as the key in fixture cache, it is replaced with the matching fixture value.

Comment: `pytest` invokes a lot of metaprogramming machinery, so the resulting test code is (almost) never executed the way it was written. This way, `pytest` does a lot of dull monotone work, while you can concentrate on the task of writing tests.